# How to dissuade my cat from jumping on my bed?

Tags: cats, training, psychology, containment

During the day, my cat loves to jump on my bed to groom himself there or have a nice nap. But I don't like that, because I don't like cat hair on my bed, and also as he is free to go out, he brings in some dirt on his feet.

Each time that he does jump on my bed, I rush to take him off and make some kind of threatening sound like "heeeyyy", but this does not prevent him from doing that again as soon as I'm not paying attention.

I‌ have put soft cushions spots around the room, but he is uninterested. His favorite spot remains to be the bed. His next best favorite spot is my desk's chair, but that is usually occupied by myself during the day.

So wondering, what are some simple and humane solutions to dissuade him?

Comment: For how long are you trying to teach him? How fast do you react when you recognize? Do you always take him off or are there situations where you are too tired or you think it is ok, because he is clean. Are there alternatives for him which are not at the ground?

Comment: "your bed" ? it's the cats bed ;-) i'm not allowed to close my bedroom, when i do (i don't) the cat starts making such a noise behind the door that i can't sleep. anyway they like "your bed" because it's warm, offer some equaly warm spots, like a heated cushion, but in the end you will wake up with your cat sleeping on your back. i would be very unhappy if my cat was NOT sleeping on my bed, but that's me, my cat sleeps on my pillow next to my head :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cats like their comfort, so this is a tricky one. Also, they don't respond well to negative training, since they are not pack animals. In this regard, they are as crafty as old men.

You could cover your bed with something, e.g. chairs, to make it less inviting, or you could put something on it that your cat knows that it's OK to sleep on. My cat uses an old gardening jacket that I have provided. Generally, he stays on it (see photo). Oddly enough, cat hairs are not much of a problem, since he is very fastidious about grooming himself, and I normally groom him when he comes for a cuddle.

I also have a cat bed that hangs on my radiator, and is comfortably off the floor (and nice and warm when the central heating is on). He seems to like being near me during the day, and to be able to sleep off the floor. Shelves are also good places for cat snoozes, providing they are accessible.

**Edit:**

Thinking about it a little more: my old gardening jacket does get dirty and needs washing regularly, but it attracts few cat hairs. However, a cotton winceyette blanket that he also sleeps on **does** attract a lot of hairs, so it very much depends on the type of material that you use. The jacket has a fairly loose "twill" weave, if that is helpful.

[image]

[image]

Canac Cat Radiator Bed

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes the best path is protection. A fitted sheet can be used on top of the bed, when the cat might have unsupervised access to the bed (new or gently used). This will keep the bed clean when you are not watching.  It is easy to put on and take off, as well as quick and easy to wash and dry.

Comment: 3 years after the question, and I ended up using this idea. I just put a cheap but thick   sheet and it works great.

Answer (score 4):

Cats normally avoid a very soft resting area. A harder resting area is better and feels safer for a cat (from a cat's view).

You can try to get a cat bed with a firmer surface and put your used T-shirt on it. Your cat will love it.

One reason for your cat jumping onto your bed is that it smells of you and this attracts the cat. This reaction is the same as when you come home. It rubs against you to mark you and exchange smells. Your cat has positive feelings about you.

The T-shirt trick does work -- just think about this. Cats do often rest in laundry baskets because they smell of us.

You might not avoid the cat jumping into your bed from time to time, but it will do this less often.

Another trick I use to avoid fur in my bed is to fold up a towel and put this on my bed. My cat lies on this and not on the rest of my bed (it is best to use an old hard towel and not a new soft one).

Answer (score 0):

Don't want cat hair on your bed, right. Eliminate the hair by brushing the cat often.

As to getting on your bed, the only sure way to prevent it is to keep the bedroom door closed.

A dog could be "instructed" to stay off your bed without taking it personally, but not a cat.

Basically, I think you consider your cat to be a dog, as I said a dog could be convinced to stay off the bed.

A cat, however, properly thinks that everything, every surface, place, and thing is their property and if they want to sleep on it, they well.

Best to keep the door closed - or get a dog.

As to the chair being a favorite spot but it is occupied by you - a human's lap was designed solely as a place for cats to sleep. Let your cat sleep there - there is nothing better than a cat asleep on your lap to make the universe bearable for yet another day. Well, a cat sleeping curled up next to you, touching you is just as good.